# Kendo-UI min/max setters not a function

Tags: kendo-ui

Kendo-UI slider min/max functions when used as setters they throw an error

> Uncaught TypeError: slider.max is not a function at line 6

Does anyone know if this will be fixed soon and is there a workaround for it right now?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Kendo UI Slider doesn't have min/max methods and also setOptions will not update the range, observable in [this Dojo demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/IriBa).

I'll strongly recommend to post your findings in Kendo UI issue tracker:

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues

As to a possible workaround, my assumption is that you will need to recreate the component with new min/max range, smth like that:

http://dojo.telerik.com/iFEQI